# IntelliJ project structurevs lib.xml mismatch

Tags: intellij-idea

An image can explain this better than I could. Version 3.7 showing in the project directory is the correct one that I want to use. The version in the Project Structure dialog no longer exists. Where is IntelliJ storing that information?

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot]

Comment: Check the iml file, it may be added directly to the module dependencies, not as a separate library, refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Comment: The iml references yet another version of the library (3.4) so presumably it isn't in use.

Comment: If it wasn't obvious, I don't really know what I'm doing in Java in general, not just IntelliJ.